Alienware 15 R3 wifi temperature is rising
I got a used Alienware 15 R3 computer and installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Desktop version.
After 2-3 hours, mostly studying and watching materials from youtube the wifi connection is very bad and seems that the temperature is also rising.
ath10k_hwmon-pci-3d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +47.0°C
Normally temperature is 47 degrees, and maximum what have seen is 67 degrees.

What is the question?
